Correcting GPS time incoherances in a LAS file
I am Working in R using the lidr package to do tree canopy delination. When I am checking my LAS file I receive the following messages:
Warning: There are 11063 points flagged 'withheld'.
Checking the data

Checking coordinates... ✓
Checking coordinates type... ✓
Checking coordinates range... ✓
Checking coordinates quantization... ✓
Checking attributes type... ✓
Checking ReturnNumber validity... ✓
Checking NumberOfReturns validity... ✓
Checking ReturnNumber vs. NumberOfReturns... ✓
Checking RGB validity... ✓
Checking absence of NAs... ✓
Checking duplicated points...
⚠ 4 points are duplicated and share XYZ coordinates with other points
Checking degenerated ground points...
⚠ There were 1 degenerated ground points. Some X Y Z coordinates were repeated
⚠ There were 34 degenerated ground points. Some X Y coordinates were repeated but with different Z coordinates
Checking attribute population...
 'EdgeOfFlightline' attribute is not populated
Checking gpstime incoherances
**✗ 6157 pulses (points with the same gpstime) have points with identical ReturnNumber
Checking flag attributes...**
 11063 points flagged 'withheld'
Checking user data attribute... ✓
Checking the header
Checking header completeness... ✓
Checking scale factor validity... ✓
Checking point data format ID validity... ✓
Checking extra bytes attributes validity... ✓
Checking the bounding box validity... ✓
Checking coordinate reference system... ✓
Checking header vs data adequacy
Checking attributes vs. point format... ✓
Checking header bbox vs. actual content... ✓
Checking header number of points vs. actual content... ✓
Checking header return number vs. actual content... ✓
Checking coordinate reference system...
Checking if the CRS was understood by R... ✓
Checking preprocessing already done
Checking ground classification... yes
Checking normalization... no
Checking negative outliers... ✓
Checking flightline classification... yes
Checking compression
Checking attribute compression...
EdgeOfFlightline is compressed
Synthetic_flag is compressed
Keypoint_flag is compressed
UserData is compressed

How do I correct GPS time incoherances in a las file? I am quite new to LiDAR Processing and R but I have used the Lidr CRAN PDF and Lidr package R book to help guide me but I am unsure how to proceed.

Before attempting to fix the data, it's crucial to identify the root cause of the problem. Without understanding the source, it's impossible to provide meaningful help.
You mentioned having a few duplicated gpstime values—does this indicate an issue with the data provider? Are these points unusual in some way? Where are they located? Is the gpstime value zero, or does it look valid? Are the points flagged withheld?
There could be countless reasons for anomalies in a dataset, and unfortunately, you've provided no context or details to help diagnose the issue.
